# How to hide bottom toolbar in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Is there any way to show the video, without the bottom toolbar in VLC, using windowed mode?

I found a cvlc parameter/command but I think it just hides the whole VLC window including hiding the video itself. And the cvlc always gave me error: "couldn't find file or directory bla bla"

Comment: May also want to turn off "OSD" in subtitles area...

Answer (score 3):

In VLC player:

1.Click `Tools -> Preferences` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to bring Preferences dialog box.
2. In *Preferences* dialog box, click "Interface" and check "**Start in minimal view mode**" and click save.

To toggle hide/show the toolbar, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>
[image]

The Hidden toolbar in windowed mode:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The setting is `Minimal Interface`.

You'll find this option in the menu under `View`.  (Right click the video) -> (point to) `View` -> (Click) `Minimal Interface`.

You'll see this toggle as well as other toggles which will include the keyboard short cuts, which in this case is <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

You can also find the `View` settings in the Menu Bar.